# Unable to print success messages after data is successful file upload in jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I am new to Jquery, Ajax and php, 
I written a program , which upload file to a database as a blob file , i succeeded in uploading the file to the database. but here comes a problem , now i am unable to print the success message in the `<div id="msg"></div>` section, after the file is being submitted. i tried the other ways and questions given in stackover flow but none worked out for me. the file 
"**index.php**"

contains code for ajax and file upload, where as the upload.php contains logic for inserting the file into database.

**index.php**

```
<?php include_once 'dbconfig.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>File upload</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button").click(function() {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'upload.php',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : formData,
                    processData: false,  
                    contentType: false, 
                    success : function(data) {
                        //console.log(data);
                        document.getElementbyID("msg").innerHTML()="";
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <tt>Upload file</tt>
    </div>
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <form id="form" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <button id="button" name="button"/>Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
    include_once 'dbconfig.php';

    $file = rand(1000, 100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder = "upload/";

    // new file size in KiloByte
    $new_size = $file_size / 1024;
    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    $final_file=str_replace(' ', '-', $new_file_name);

    if (move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder.$final_file)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO files(file) VALUES('$final_file')";
        mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        mysqli_close($connection);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to print response into php first. Add `print "File uploaded successfully!!";` after `mysqli_close($connection);` line.
JQuery code seems to be correct.

```css
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

try {
         $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
         $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
         $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
         $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
         $folder="upload/";

         // new file size in KiloByte
         $new_size = $file_size/1024;
         // make file name in lower case
         $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
         $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

         if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
         {
              $sql="INSERT INTO files(file) VALUES('$final_file')";  
              mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
                        
              print "success";
         }
         else
        {
          print "error";
         }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    print "error";
    }finally {
   mysqli_close($connection);  
  }
?>
```

Comment: i tried that but dosent work, i want to print my message into the div. (i.e: <div id="msg"></div>)

Comment: Have you tried $("#msg").html(data) this in success event of JQuery Ajax ?

Comment: yeah i tried that too but, didn't give me any change

Comment: i updated code like this $.ajax({

                   url : 'upload.php',
                   type : 'POST',
                   data : formData,
                   processData: false,  
                   contentType: false, 
                   success : function(data) 
                       {
                            //console.log(data);
                           // document.getElementbyID("msg").innerHTML()="";
                            $("#msg").html(data)
                           // alert(data);
                       }
                  

              });

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `echo` command in your php code and with `echo` you will be return a **flag** or **message** to understand your result of operation.

**In upload.php :**

```
<?php
 include_once 'dbconfig.php';

 try {
     $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
     $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
     $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
     $folder="upload/";

     // new file size in KiloByte
     $new_size = $file_size/1024;
     // make file name in lower case
     $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
     $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

     if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
     {
          $sql="INSERT INTO files(file) VALUES('$final_file')";  
          mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

          print "success";
     }
     else
    {
      print "error";
     }
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
  print "error";
}finally {
 mysqli_close($connection);  
}
?>
```

**In index page :**

```
            $.ajax({
                   url : 'upload.php',
                   type : 'POST',
                   data : formData,
                   processData: false,  
                   contentType: false, 
                   success : function(data) 
                       {
                        if(data ='success')                               

                          document.getElementbyID("msg").innerHTML()="success.";

                       }
                   });
```